# Select from foreign table with join and output JSON - Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models `Article` and `Language`. `Article has_many :languages` and `Language belongs_to: :article`.
I have method for selecting articles with their languages in `Article` model:

```
def self.per_page(limit, offset)
  left_joins(:languages)
  .limit(limit).offset(offset)
  .select('articles.id, articles.title, languages.language')
  .group(:id)
end
```

I call this method in `articles_controller.rb`:

```
def index
  limit = 40
  @articles = Article.per_page(limit, params[:offset])
  byebug
  render json: @articles
end
```

I have in `articles` one row with `id=105` and three rows in `languages` table with `article_id=105`
The problem is that it selects only the first row per related article in languages table, but not all.
Now JSON looks like:

```
{
    id: 105
    title: 'Some title',
    language: 'English'
}
```

I want to select all articles with all related to them languages and JSON output to be like :

```
{
    id: 105
    title: 'Some title',
    language: ['English', 'French', ...]
}
```

How can I do that ?
It is not a problem if it is more than one request in the controller.

Comment: Do you really want a language to ever only belong to one article? I'm not sure what your use scenario is but you probably want to use a join table to create a many to many association.

Comment: Also, the `ruby-on-rails-x` tags are for questions regarding a particular version of rails - don't add them all just to get attention - it does not work and makes a mess.

Comment: Ok, sorry. The relation must be one-to-many.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your associations are not properly defined. If you add a `belongs_to` association to the `Language` model a language can only ever belong to a single article.

Instead you want something like this:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :translations
  has_many :languages, through: :translations
end

class Translation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :language
end

class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :translations
  has_many :articles, through: :translations
end
```

This creates a many-to-many association with `translations` as a join table.

Comment: I can't explain, but it must be one-to-many. In this case how can I make the selection ? Imagine that the table is not `languages`, but assets or something other.

Comment: You can use `eager_load` or `includes` and load the associated records and iterate through them. Or if your database allows it you can use an aggregate function for example: `.select('articles.id, articles.title, json_agg(articles.languages)')` in Postgres.

Comment: `includes` doesn't return any language. I see I need to loop through `@articles`, but how to do that and add `languages` for each item in the JSON ?

Comment: I would use ActiveModelSerializers or JBuilder to create the json. You can do it by monkeying with `as_json` but its not recommended.

Comment: Awesome ! JBuilder really helps me to implement this. Just a question, is there a way without `JBuidrer` with loops in the controller ? Because I can't add property languages to the Article object.

Comment: You can use map to iterate through the collection and just return a hash from each model instance. But that can be done in jbuilder as well and does not give you a fat controller